# Why doesn't `sudo su -l -c "java"` work even though `sudo su -l -c "echo $PATH"` displays the location of the java binary?

Tags: environment-variables, su, bashrc

I have a server with Java binaries from a tarball on a custom location, and the following in `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

When I run `sudo su -l -c "java"`, I get `-su: java: command not found`. However, when I `sudo su -l` in directly, I can run `java` without errors.

Furthermore, `sudo su -l -c "echo $PATH` includes the location of `java`.

Why does `sudo su -l -c "java"` fail to run?

EDIT: Even though it is `/etc/bash.bashrc` and not `~/.bashrc`, the same reasoning applies in the linked question/answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dhag explained why `$PATH` appears to be correct, even though it isn't.

The reason the path doesn't get changed is most likely that `su` doesn't run the shell interactively, meaning that either bash.bashrc doesn't get executed in the first place, or that it quits before doing anything because it detects that it's not running interactively.

You'll either have to specify the full path instead of the command name, or find out where the default path is set and change it there.

Comment: Just realized it. Marking my own question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `sudo su -l -c "echo $PATH"`, `$PATH` is expanded in your original shell, because the double quotes do not prevent this expansion. You want `sudo su -l -c 'echo $PATH'` to expand in the `su` shell instead.

I assume a follow-up question will be "then how do I get `java` to run"? I would suggest either calling java with its full path, or, and this may or may not work, by manually attempting to load the proper rc file, something like `su -c '. /etc/bash.bashrc; java ...'`.

Comment: derp. I was more interested in why `sudo su -l -c "java"` fails, but I guess that'll have to go in a separate question.

Comment: Yep; as @Ringstaart suggests, the answer probably lies in the way `su` acts on its `-l` option.

Comment: `su -c '. /etc/bash.bashrc; java ...'` didn't work =[